# how do we allow WebView to accept Self-Signed (internal) Certificates?

Tags: android, mobile, ssl, webview, self-signed

Android WebView with https Url shows blank/empty page. So how do we allow WebView to accept Self-Signed (internal) Certificates?

Comment: any solution on this?